# Is any mention about Siddhambika in scriptures?

Tags: identification-request, devi

I have heard about Goddess Siddhambika, from a temple in Juna Disa. But, Does any scriptures mention about this goddess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siddhambika is mentioned in [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc366034.html) of Kumarika khanda of Skanda Purana.

> 10-11. Four great Śaktis are established in the four quarters (of this Tīrtha). **Siddhāṃbikā** was installed by Guha in the East. It is proclaimed that she was created from the primordial Prakṛti at the beginning (of the creation) of the universe. Since she was propitiated by Siddhas, she is (known as) **Siddhāṃbikā**.

The above text mentioned Siddhambika summoned from primordinal Prakiti means Devi Adi Shakti at the creation of the universe and she was worshipped by Siddhas.

And she also mentioned as one of seven Siddha deities in [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc366022.html) of the same Kumarika khanda.

> If a person worships the seven Siddhas, visits them or remembers them, he is liberated from all the sins and blemishes. The seven Siddhas are: Siddheśvara, Siddhavaṭa, **Siddhāṃbikā**, Siddhavināyaka, Siddheya-Kṣetrādhipati (see verse 29), Siddhasaras and Siddhakūpa.